# How to prevent duplicate usernames when people register?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, duplicates

I have been making a login/register system and I am drawing close to finishing my register portion of code. The only problem I am running into is how to make it so that users cannot register with duplicated usernames. I want it to work so that my database won't accept the information, and it will tell the user about the error.

My PHP

```
<?php

include 'database_connection.php';
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])) {
    $error = array(); //Declare An Array to store any error message
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {//if no name has been supplied
    $error[] = 'Please Enter a name '; //add to array "error"
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name']; //else assign it a variable
}

    if (empty($_POST['e-mail'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter your Email ';
    } else {
        if (preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+)+$/", $_POST['e-mail'])) {
            //regular expression for email validation
            $Email = $_POST['e-mail'];
        } else {
            $error[] = 'Your EMail Address is invalid  ';
        }
    }

    if (empty($_POST['Password'])) {
        $error[] = 'Please Enter Your Password ';
    } else {
        $Password = $_POST['Password'];
    }

    if (empty($error)) {
        //send to Database if there's no error '
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use custom regexes for validating e-mail addresses, valid e-mail addresses allows a + sign in the local part. use filter_input(INPUT_POST, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this when the user post the username for example and click submit you can write this code using mysqli:

```
<?php

// make sure the error reporting is enabled!
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$username = $_POST['username'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM table_name where username=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_row();
if ($user) {
    $error[] = "This username is already taken!";
}
```

When you create the column of the user you can make it unique, for example create table users(username varchar(350) not null unique).

Comment: Please, don't use the given code. It's widely open for SQL injection

Comment: Not only is it open to SQL injection, the code does not work when two or more users register at the same time with the same username. The best solution is to use a UNIQUE index, or wrap this code in a transaction.

Comment: @NicoHaase luckily, this is a community-edited website, so the community could always improve the existing answers.

Comment: @Code4R7 thanks to the community effort, both issues are fixed now

Answer (score 21):

**The best way to prevent duplicate usernames in the database is to add a  UNIQUE index for the column**

```sql
-- Make it unique
ALTER TABLE users ADD UNIQUE (username);
```

This will prevent duplicate records in the table with the same username. When you try to insert the same one then an error will be generated.

You can then catch the exception in PHP and check the reason. The duplicate constraint SQL error code is 1062.

Here is an example of how to catch this error when using PDO:

```php
$error = [];
$username = 'Dharman';

$pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8mb4", 'user', 'password', [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,  // make sure the error reporting is enabled!
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
]);

try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username) VALUE(?)');
    $stmt->execute([$username]);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->errorInfo[1] === 1062) {
        $error[] = "This username is already taken!";
    } else {
        throw $e; // let the exception to be processed further 
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how to catch this error when using mysqli:

```php
$error = [];
$username = 'Dharman';

// make sure the error reporting is enabled!
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'test');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8mb4');

try {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO users(username) VALUE(?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() === 1062) {
        $error[] = "This username is already taken!";
    } else {
        throw $e; // let the exception to be processed further 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to to set unique constraint on field "username" without that field id primary key ? However i'm agree with your solution of unique constraint.

Comment: Is there anyway of working out what is the duplicate column, as it may be common to use e-mail addresses as well.  Sometimes these must be unique as well as the username.

Comment: @NigelRen Yes, the exception message contains the name of the column. You can use regex to get it, but this is out of scope of this answer.

Comment: The extraction of the column name is as you say another problem, just wanted to make clear that if multiple unique columns are defined that this will still work (it doesn't have to be the only unique column).

Comment: After the discussion on Reddit, I am too inclined to think that catching would be overkill. Constraint+select query should be enough. In such a rare (next to imaginary) case when two guys will try to register with the same name, the loser will just get a regular server error and next time will be told it's taken. but well this solution is already present in the other answer.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Can you share the link to the discussion? The idea is that a duplicate username isn't a system error and shouldn't produce a generic error message. While a select query would work 99.99% of the time, it's not much cleaner than catching the exception. Furthermore, some designs do this in 2-step approach. First request validates the data and the second submits. There could be a significant delay in such a poor design and if the end user isn't notified why the submission failed, they won't know to try a different username.

Comment: [Not much a discussion though](https://old.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/w7jdr5/prevent_duplicate_usernames_when_people_register/ihkfefy/)

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you should do.

1. Make the user name a primary key in the database table. This is easily done using phpmyadmin.
2. Validate prior to insert.

For the second step, here's an algorithm. You may implement it in your own way using pdo, mysqli or even mysql (although it's not recommended now).

Algorithm at the end of your code (i.e., if there aren't errors)...

> Select records that match the USERNAME supplied in the post.
>
> If it exists, give out an error.
>
> If it doesn't exist, insert it.

Comment: The critical thing here is that the index is UNIQUE not that it is primary; though it’s strictly correct that a primary key is always unique.  Thus, the answer above is more helpful than this one.

Answer (score 3):

I used a PDO and class method, may be of some use.

```
//function for checking if the user already exists in the database
public function userExists($username)
{
    //prepared statements for added security
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username`= ?");
    //execute the query
    $query->execute([$username]);
    $rows = $query->fetchColumn();

    //if a row is returned...user already exists
    return ($rows > 0);
}
```

note the prepared statements too - definitely the way forward