# Why php code does not filter the existing records from the MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I try to make a data uploading system. If the data exists in the MySQL database it should not upload it. Now my code is uploading everything and not filtering the duplicant.

my code:

```
<?php
    include 'settings.php';

    $msg = '';

    if(isset($_POST['rogzit'])) {

        $vonalkod = $_POST['vonalkod'];
        $garnitura = $_POST['garnitura'];

        if(isset($_POST['vonalkod']) && isset($_POST['garnitura'])) {

            } else if (strlen($vonalkod) > 12) {
                $msg = '<h4 class="col-12 text-center mb-3 text-danger">Nem megfelelő a vonalkód beolvasása!</h4>';
            } else if(strlen($vonalkod) < 12) {
                $msg = '<h4 class="col-12 text-center mb-3 text-danger">Nem megfelelő a vonalkód beolvasása!</h4>';
            } else {
            $result_vonalkodCheck = "SELECT azon FROM G0004 WHERE vonalkod LIKE '$vonalkod'";
            
            if(empty($result_vonalkodCheck)) {
            $msg = '<h4 class="col-12 text-center mb-3 text-danger">A termék már volt rögzítve!</h4>';
            }
        }
        if(empty($msg)){
            $sql_beszuras = "INSERT INTO G0004(vonalkod, garnitura) VALUES ('$vonalkod', '$garnitura')";
            if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql_beszuras)) {
                $msg = '<h4 class="col-12 text-center mb-3 text-success">Sikeres rögzítés!</h4>';
            } else {
            $msg = '<h4 class="col-12 text-center mb-3 text-danger">Sikertelen rögzítés!</h4>';
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: You never execute your `SELECT` query against the database to observe any results.

Comment: Thank you! What should I do? I'm new in coding

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: You should execute SQL statement to fetch the data from the database.

Comment: @TóthLászló: At this point if your question is "How do I read data from a database in PHP?" then you're at the point where you can use your favorite search engine to find tutorials and examples on the subject.  Note of course that there are plenty of *bad* tutorials out there too.  In this case you'll want to focus on ones that use prepared statements with query parameters.  Any examples which directly concatenate values into the SQL query like your code does should be avoided.

Comment: I know this is not perfect this is my first own project. Thank you for the help. The problem is with this line:

Comment: else {
            $result_vonalkodCheck = "SELECT azon FROM G0004 WHERE vonalkod LIKE '$vonalkod'";
            if(empty($result_vonalkodCheck)) {
            $msg = '<h4 class="col-12 text-center mb-3 text-danger">A termék már volt rögzítve!</h4>';
            }
        }

Comment: If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicates then you should set a unique index on `vonalkod`. Then MySQL will handle the duplicate checking and prevent one being inserted.

Comment: Thank you for the advices! The best solution for this problem was the unique index was Thank you Tangentially Perpendicular

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736421/how-to-prevent-duplicate-usernames-when-people-register

Answer (score -1):

You need first to check whether the value entered in the input field is matched with the records saved from your database table. If entered value matched the record from your database table then prompt the user that the record already exist, and if not, then insert new record.

```
<?php
include 'settings.php';

$msg = '';

if(isset($_POST['rogzit'])) {

    $vonalkod = $_POST['vonalkod'];
    $garnitura = $_POST['garnitura'];

    $check_record = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM G0004 WHERE vonalkod='$vonalkod' AND garnitura='$garnitura' ")or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn));
    if(mysqli_num_rows($check_record)){ //check record if exist
        $msg = "Record already exist!";
    }
    elseif(strlen($vonalkod) > 12 || strlen($vonalkod) < 12){ //check if barcode has valid string length
        $msg = "The barcode is not scanned correctly!";
    }
    else{ //insert new record
        $insert_query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO G0004(vonalkod,garnitura)VALUES('$vonalkod','$garnitura')")or trigger_error(mysqli_error($conn));
        $msg = "Record Inserted!";
    }

}
?>
```