# Mysqli fetch array from stored prepared statement resulted in an error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am working on a user registration page. I want to check if the username or email exist before an account is created. I saved the stored query from the prepared statement into the variable "$result" using `mysqli_stmt_get_result` and tried to fetch the result using `mysqli_fetch_array`, but I got an error that read;

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in localhost

The codes below resulted in "result empty". This is the main issue.

```
$result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
if($result) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {                 
        if($row['username']==$username && $row['email']==$useremail){
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=error&usernametaken&emailexist");
            exit();
        }
        elseif($row['username']==$username){
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=error&usernametaken");
            exit();
        }
        elseif($row['email']==$useremail){
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=error&emailexist");
            exit();
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "result is empty";

}
```

**Below is the full code**

```
$sql = "SELECT username, email FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    header("Location: ../register.php?error=sqlerror");
    exit();
}
else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $username, $useremail); 
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    //check if the username exist
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
    $rowCount = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);    
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    
    if($rowCount > 0) {
        if($result) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {                 
                if($row['username']==$username && $row['email']==$useremail){
                    header("Location: ../register.php?error=error&usernametaken&emailexist");
                    exit();
                }
                elseif($row['username']==$username){
                    header("Location: ../register.php?error=error&usernametaken");
                    exit();
                }
                elseif($row['email']==$useremail){
                    header("Location: ../register.php?error=error&emailexist");
                    exit();
                }
            }
        } else {
            echo "result is empty";

        }               
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, name, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn); 
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) { 
            header("Location: ../register.php?error=sqlerror");
            exit();
        } else {     
            $hashedPass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);     
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $username, $useremail, $first_name, $hashedPass); 
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            header("Location: ../register.php?success&registered");
        }
    }

}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);
```

I am running it on a local server though. I humbly await your input.

Comment: It would be so much easier for you to use PDO. Why are you not using PDO yet? Is there any reason why you are suffering with mysqli?

Comment: Relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736421/how-to-prevent-duplicate-usernames-when-people-register

Comment: Just to let you know, that Dani Krossing whose videos you are learning from, is an impostor, who knows no programming at all. As a result, you won't learn any programming as well.